# File csproj : how to create a nuget package with msbuild and with package dependencies?

Tags: package, dependencies, nuget, csproj

Hello,
in a .csproj file, I create a nuget package with msbuild.
All works, except that I want this package is dependent of another nuget packages.
**These packages are NOT referenced in the project**. They are just available in the packages source.

In a nuspec file, I would write something like :

```
`<dependencies>
   <dependency id="otherNugetPackage1" version="2.0.8">
   <dependency id="otherNugetPackage2" version="1.0.55">
</dependencies>`
```

But how could I do the same thing in the csproj file ? In which section please ?

Thank you
Chris

I tried to add the "dependencies" section at the top of the csproj, at the same level as "PackageId".
But not sure if it's possible, if it's the good syntax, and which location in the csproj I should put it ... ?

Not found any example about that on the web.